# How to use Toast in ASyncTask/onPostExecute with string from resources?

Tags: android, resources, toast, android-asynctask

I have the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void arg0) {
                    ...
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.toast_sync_completed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It fails (FC). If pass `"Test string"` instead of `getResources().getString(R.string.toast_sync_completed)`, then it works correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this code :
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.toast_sync_completed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change getBaseContext()... to getApplicationContext().....

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.toast_sync_completed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Actually it works both with ApplicationContext and BaseContext - the problem was in another code.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
For me it's not working. Error shows: The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type SingupMember

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
public static void myprofsList(Activity context){
 static Context = mConext;

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

      Toast toast=Toast.makeText(mConext,"Succefully Updated Profile Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

  }
}
```

you've to just pass your string file.